# What server is behind express

Tags: express, webserver

I have seen that in many languages, a web framework is built on top of web server, and maybe middle-ware application. For example:

- Ruby on Rails is powered by a Webrick web server, and rack middleware
- Most Python frameworks run on WSGI servers

I know that Express is powered by Connect middle-ware , but what server does it run on. A node.js HTTP server? A custom server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Express is built upon the node.js core `http` module in combination with the connect middleware ecosystem. This implementation is a custom implementation that is part of node.js, and the networking and filesystem pieces are further based upon the libuv asynchronous I/O library.